# Send Cowrie output to kippo-graph

Tags: php, honeypot

I followed the tutorial how to send Cowrie output to Kippo-Graph from this website
[How to send Cowrie output to kippo-graph](https://cowrie.readthedocs.io/en/latest/kippo-graph/README.html)

But I get an error in the rb.php file which is in the `/var/www/html/kippo-graph/include/` directory,
And when I access the kippo-graph web and click on one of the menus on the website, I get an error message that is "500 internal error"

Error log `/var/log/apache2/error.log`

> [Thu Apr 06 01:49:53.571368 2023] [php:error] [pid 20977] [client localhost:42856] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected namespaced name "implements\IteratorAggregate", expecting "{" in /var/www/html/kippo-graph/include/rb.php on line 1029, referer: http://localhost/kippo-graph/kippo-playlog.php
> [Thu Apr 06 01:49:54.082741 2023] [php:error] [pid 18486] [client localhost:42872] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected namespaced name "implements\IteratorAggregate", expecting "{" in /var/www/html/kippo-graph/include/rb.php on line 1029, referer: http://localhost/kippo-graph/kippo-ip.php
> [Thu Apr 06 01:50:21.933234 2023] [php:error] [pid 20977] [client localhost:35264] PHP Parse error:  syntax **error, unexpected namespaced name "implements\IteratorAggregate", expecting "{" in /var/www/html/kippo-graph/include/rb.php on line 1029, referer: http://localhost/kippo-graph/

Can someone provide information or assistance regarding this problem? I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you.

I want to visualize Cowrie output to Kippo-Graphs

Comment: `PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected namespaced name "implements\IteratorAggregate", expecting "{" in /var/www/html/kippo-graph/include/rb.php on line 1029` - Have you checked there?

Comment: You forgot to share the code involved. Also, is this a PHP question, a MySQL question, or one related to any honeypot?